# TextView show html

Tags: html, json, kotlin

So I am trying to print HTML code in my TextView. however it is having issues with `<p></p>` lines and I am try to work out how to make it do what it is meant to do instead it is showing as

[image: Screenshot of code]

The code I am using.

```
holder?.view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.episodeDescription)?.setText(Html.fromHtml(ProgramName.description.toString(),  HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH))
```

JSON code

```
<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back join show host Yvonne Fletcher and Gill The Scottish Terrier, Gemma Frances and Hoursty representing a few of the comedians supporting The Open Mic Comedy Night Stand Up for India presented by NY Events! This event will donate $5 per ticket sold to Sewa Internationals appeal to assist India during their current COVID-19 crisis.</p><p>Could we please add comedy fundraising  event tickets available <a href=\"https://www.nyevents.com.au/comedy\" alt=\"NYEvents Comedy\" target=\"_blank\">www.nyevents.com.au/comedy</a> #comedy #perthradiostation #perth #perthlife #comedian #australia #digitalradio #covid19 #standupcomedy</p>]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `string.split("<p>","</p>")` and using the returned string list may help.